# Proof of hint in Rudin exercise concerning countability of algebraic numbers

Tags: real-analysis

The problem from Rudin's POMA is reproduced below:

> **Exercise 2.2:** A complex number $z$ is said to be *algebraic* if there are integers $a_0,\ldots,a_n$, not all zero, such that
>   $$
> a_0z^n+a_1z^{n-1}+\cdots+a_{n-1}z+a_n=0.
> $$
>   Prove that the set of all algebraic numbers is countable. *Hint:* For every positive integer $N$ there are only finitely many equations with
>   $$
> n+|a_0|+|a_1|+\cdots+|a_n|=N.
> $$

I think I've worked out how to use the hint effectively, but I'm curious as to the justification of the hint itself.

**Ideas:** Any positive integer $N$ effectively puts a bound on the order of the polynomials under consideration, namely $N-1$. The bound on the order of the polynomial also puts a bound on the number of coefficients being considered regardless of their value. Now, I know that a polynomial of order $n$ has at most $n$ distinct roots--how can I use that to good effect here?

If, say, $N=7$, then the order of the polynomials under consideration can be at most $6$ (otherwise all the coefficients would have to be 0 which is not permitted). If we are looking at a polynomial of degree 6, then we may only have *one* coefficient with a nonzero value, and that nonzero value would have to be 1.

Am I on the right track here? I'm not sure how to formalize this reasoning (or if it's even worth formalizing).

Comment: Given $z$ a root of $P(x) = \sum_{m=0}^n a_m x^m \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ irreducible, let $N(P) = n+\sum_{m=0}^n |a_m|$, then you can enumerate the polynomials with increasing $N(Q)$ and for each check if $z$ is a root of $Q$ (looking at $\gcd(P,Q) \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$). You'll necessary find a $Q$ with $Q(z) = 0$.

Comment: Sorry, I don't really understand this comment or how exactly it proves the hint (I imagine my misunderstanding may be due to the fact that I do not have much of an algebraic background).

Comment: The idea is it partition all possible polynomials (and therefore their algebraic number roots) into a countable number of finite sets.  This is a strange and think outside the box way to do it, but there are only a finite number of polynomial where the sum of the coeeficients and the degree is $N$ that's one finite set.  The union for every $N$ will contain all possible polynomials

Answer (score 3):

What Rudin is saying in his usual cryptic fashion is that you should associate to each $N$ a finite set of algebraic numbers (call it $X_N$), and then you should prove that {algebraic numbers} $\subset \bigcup X_N$.

For example, with $N=2$, you have just two possibilities for integer polynomials:
$n=1, a_0=1, a_1=0$, OR
$n=1, a_0=-1, a_1=0$
corresponding to the polynomials
$z$ and $-z$.

For $N=3$, you have
\begin{align*}
n=1, a_0=1, a_1=1 \\
n=1, a_0=-1, a_1=1 \\
n=1, a_0=1, a_1=-1 \\
n=1, a_0=-1, a_1=-1 \\
n=2, a_0=1, a_1=0, a_0=0 \\
n=2, a_0=-1, a_1=0, a_0=0 \\
\end{align*}
and all the polynomials which those represent.

Let $X_N$ be the roots corresponding to all the polynomials listed for a given $N$. By (# roots $\leq$ degree), and the fact that there is a finite list of polynomials for each $N$, $X_N$ is finite. For instance, you can roughly bound $|X_2|\leq2$ and $|X_3|\leq 8$ above.

After you've proven that every algebraic number belongs to some $X_N$, you can use the fact that a countable union of countable (finite in this case) sets is countable.

Comment: Thanks--I'm still trying to figure out how to use essentially a counting argument to come up with an upper bound for the number of polynomials associated with each $N$ (as you came up with 8 for $N=3$). Also, given the issue of boundedness is at play here as opposed to the exact number of complex roots, I don't think FTA is necessary so much as the claim that a polynomial of degree $k$ has at most $k$ roots right?

Comment: Whoops, I was grasping for the name of the fact that a degree $n$ polynomial has at most $n$ roots.

Comment: To see that the number of polynomials corresponding to $N$ is bounded, you should note that $n+|a_0|+\cdots+|a_n|$ is a "partition" of $N$ and that's definitely finite. For example, an extremely rough bound on the number of partitions of $N$ is $N^N$

Comment: In our situation, the partitions actually include potentially zero terms. Given $N$, you can have at most $N+1$ summands, each of which takes values between $0 and N$. So the number of polynomials on our list will be at most $(N+1)^(N+1)$

Answer (score 2):

This seems a bit perverse but if you can find the following sets:

For each $n \in \mathbb N$ there is a set $A_n$ containing at most some finite number of $k_n$ polynomials, and the polynomials are of some maximum $m_n$ degree then there is a set $B_n$ containing most $k_n\cdot m_n$ algebraic numbers, and if we can further do this so that $U_{n\in \mathbb N}A_n$ will contain all possible polynomials then $U_{n\in \mathbb N}B_n$ will contain all possible algebraic numbers.

And that being a countable union of finite sets is countable.

So all we have to divide all the possible polynomials into these finite sets.

Okay, we can take a polynomial $a_nx^n + .... + a_0$ and come up with a number $N = n + |a_n| + |a_{n-1}| + .... + a_0$.  And we'll simply put it in a set called $A_N$.  As every polynomial will have such a number every polynomial will get placed and as each number $N$ can only have a finite number of degrees and coefficients adding up to $N$ each $A_N$ is finite.

Ta-da!  We are done.

Now if you are like every student I have *ever* met, you will probably ask well why not just say:  For each degree of a polynomial there are only a countable number of coefficients for that possition, so there are only a countable union of countably many coeficients to determine a countable number of polynomials.

I'm not sure why that's not the intended method.  I suspect is there is one pitfall, in that is very easy to fall into the trap not noticing polynomials must be finite and making a false conclusion that the set of *infinite* sequence of integers is countable.